# Save certain input fields & save all input fields

Tags: jquery, forms

So basically I am setting up an admin panel where you can enter information and save it to the database. The admin panel has three container, one each for:

1. Personal Information
2. Educational Information
3. Password

Each container incorporates a form and a submit button. In addition to this I would like to give the user the option to have a "Save All Changes" button. This should then detect all changes within all three forms and save them to the database.

How do I go about it? My first thought was nested forms, which I read is NOT the right way to do it. My second idea was to bind a click handler to the "save all changes" button and then get the values from all input fields. However, the input fields are in three different forms. How would I refer to them? Is that even the correct way of doing it or can someone think of a better solution?

Comment: Your second idea is pretty sound, however why not wrap a single form around all three, and have a single Save All button? If you did go with the second option you can grab the inputs by a class, id, or name = $('#formOne').find('input[name="FirstName]"').val();

Comment: Thanks Syon! I could just wrap all within a single form but I was thinking it would more intuitiv to the user to have several save buttons since two containers are always collapsed and only one visible. I will try grab the input fields as you suggested and if I can't get it to work I might have to do the single form. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You can add as much submit buttons to a form as you like. No limits

Comment: You can even wrap a single form around all three, and then have jquery associated with each of the subordinate buttons to disable those sections not under the button in question while submitting.  Set disabled, submit, and then set enabled again.

Comment: Thanks BenBarden & Bondye : I will see which solutions works best for me!

Answer (score 0):

first thing. is all the information's will saved into the same table?

if yes then you might consider wrap these containers with just one form.

If no, then for future maintenance, wrap these containers with separate form. then do separate functions for save them into database. like:

```
saveContainer1IntoDB()
saveContainer2IntoDB()
saveContainer3IntoDB()
```

that way you can reuse them as needed. Finally, u catch the "Save All Changes" button click and call all three functions